# How to get P value in the accumulation density plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, statistical-test

I have a dataframe whoese strucuture is like this:

```
> str(mydata12)
'data.frame':   228459 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ intron_length: num  0.787 0.799 2.311 2.396 1.77 ...
 $ intron_type  : Factor w/ 3 levels "All_intron","All_retained_intron",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I have plotted a accumulation density figure based on this dataframe:

```
p <- ggplot(mydata12, aes(x = intron_length, color=intron_type)) + geom_step(aes(y=..y..),stat="ecdf")
```

[image]

Now I want to make the comparison by adding p values among 3 groups:

```
> compare_means(intron_length~intron_type, data = mydata12)
> my_comparisons <- list(c("All_intron", "All_retained_intron"), c("All_intron", "dynamic_intron"), c("All_retained_intron", "dynamic_intron"))
> p + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons)
Error in f(...) : 
  Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis
```

I guess I need to set a value on x axis to make comparison, my question is how to set the x axix value and add the p value?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can't super-impose what you want on top of what you have they are very different scales and axes but you can do this (I made up data since you didn't provide...

```r
  library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
  library(ggplot2)
  # Pairwise comparisons: Specify the comparisons you want
  my_comparisons <- list(c("All_intron", "All_retained_intron"), c("All_intron", "dynamic_intron"), c("All_retained_intron", "dynamic_intron"))
  ggboxplot(mydata12, x = "intron_type", y = "intron_length",
            color = "intron_type", palette = "npg")+
    # Add pairwise comparisons p-value
    stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, label.y = c(1.2, 1.3, 1.4))+
    stat_compare_means(label.y = 1.5)     # Add global Anova p-value
```

[image]

```r
mydata12 <- data.frame(intron_length = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1), 
                       intron_type = sample(c("All_intron", "All_retained_intron" , "dynamic_intron","All_retained_intron"), size = 1000, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I kind of knowing this way. Is there any way to get the slope of the curves and make a comparison?

Comment: May I suggest you take your question over to stats exchange and look for questions like this one https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115132/compare-distributions-of-two-ecdfs

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. I have seen comparison between 2 groups of accumulation density curve. Like :https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0092867415008958?token=487AE85D2B79BEC4CDEBDC56F9747B2F8E10E77803611620C145B893369B252CA27288C4A7F1FBAE8A6552FA531C13E9 (Figure1E). The method they used is:"For comparison of inter-spine distance distribution, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov two-sample-test was used. Linear regressions were performed in GraphPad Prism 5. Data distribution was assumed to be normal although not formally tested". So I am wondering if I can do the same on my data